# How to check recursive pattern data in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's assume I have input data like:

```
ID Column
-------------------
101
101UK
101IN
1002
1002AU
1002US
MARA

Output
ID Column
---------------
101
1002
MARA
```

1st row data pattern101 is repeating in row 2 & 3, so in output I need only row 1. Similarly for row 4. And as row 5 is present only once so it will be in output as it is

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ID ) AS
SELECT '101' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '101UK' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '101IN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1002' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1002AU' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1002US' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MARA' FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM   table_name m
  WHERE  t.id LIKE m.id || '%'
  AND    t.id > m.id
)
```

**Query 2**:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM   table_name
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
CONNECT BY
       PRIOR id LIKE id || '%'
AND    PRIOR id > id
```

**Output**:

Both output the same.

> ```
> | ID   |
> | :--- |
> | MARA |
> | 101  |
> | 1002 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=50f10b90d1db6bfa3cea8de6ec6f54a3)*

Answer (score 0):

With pattern recognition:

```
select strt_id as id
  from sample_table
  match_recognize (
    order by id
    measures first(strt.id) as strt_id,
             classifier() as classif
    one row per match
    after match skip past last row
    pattern (strt same*)
    define 
    same as instr(same.id, prev(strt.id)) <> 0
  ) m
  where classif = 'STRT'
  order by id;
```

Sample execution:

```
FSITJA@db01 2019-07-16 17:39:25> select strt_id as id
  2    from sample_table
  3    match_recognize (
  4      order by id
  5      measures first(strt.id) as strt_id,
  6               classifier() as classif
  7      one row per match
  8      after match skip past last row
  9      pattern (strt same*)
 10      define
 11      same as instr(same.id, prev(strt.id)) <> 0
 12    ) m
 13    where classif = 'STRT'
 14    order by id;

ID
------
1002
101
MARA
```